# Call sbt externally

Tags: scala, sbt

I am designing a tool, that takes an sbt project path as a parameter. I would like to be able to build that given project on the fly, and be able to get its classpath.

I previously designed my tool as a sbt plugin to achieve this but it is not flexible enough for my purpose: I don't want to have to parameter anything in the sbt config files of the project I am studying.

I would like to use sbt externally, construct a project (from a sbt directory path) and compile it externally in my scala code without invoking sbt in a console. This is a reproduction in code of what happens when "sbt" is typed in a given directory in the console. Is there a straightforward way to achieve this?

Comment: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-remote-control ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to look at SBT jar file and source code. Find the "Main" class and call it programmatically. The code is here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt. The main class is: `xsbt.boot.Boot`. I got it from sbt jar file by unzipping it and looking at `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. So you can see how SBT passes command line arguments to it and take it from there. Here is the `Boot` class just in case: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/launch/src/main/scala/xsbt/boot/Boot.scala. Have fun! :)

p.s. in your code just call `Boot.main(<your sbt commands>)`.

Comment: That is what I was looking for I guess. I still have the problem of having sbt itself as dependency of my project. Do I need to use unmanagedSources or something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a vaguely similar requirement. I produce a command-line tool as one of the deliverables from my project. The script launches the Scala runtime itself and naturally needs the effective class-path for the project's dependencies. To get that in an external form, I use the [SBT-Start-Script](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script) plug-in. While that plug-in does produce an actual launcher, I need to do more than it provides, so I just use it to externalize the project's (current) class-path, which I extract into a shell array initialization in a separate source file that may be `source`-ed by the main launcher script.